# SQL Server, jQgrid: Pager and search tool don't work

Tags: jquery, sql-server-2008, jqgrid

I'm VERY new to jQuery and Javascript in general so I'm having a lot of trouble trying to understand how it works. I'm working with jQgrid to show certain rows from a database running in SQL Server, I'm already able to show the information from the table and able to sort either descending or ascending, or even show more records. 
The only things that are not working are the pagination and the search tool, I really don't understand why that isn't working as I understand as soon as it loads the data, it manipulates it locally and it doesn't have to do any more requests to the server. What could it be? Also, I've done my research and I've seen that there's a variable called 'editurl' which I don't really understand its purpose.

This is my javascript code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var myGrid = $("#mygrid").jqGrid({
            url:'admanagerjson.php',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colModel: [
                {name:'Sucursal', index:'Sucursal', width:20}, 
                {name:'Pedido', index:'Pedido', width:50}, 
                {name:'PedidoAdpro', index:'PedidoAdpro', width:50},
                {name:'FechaPedido', index:'FechaPedido', width:80, align:'right'}, 
                {name:'Cancelado', index:'Cancelado', width:20}, 
                {name:'FECHA_ACT', index:'FECHA_ACT', width:80, align:'right'}, 
                {name:'FechaEntrega', index:'FechaEntrega', width:80, align:'right'}, 
                {name:'PorcDesc', index:'PorcDesc', width:50, align:'right'},
                {name:'PC', index:'PC', width:50, sortable:false},
                {name:'Cliente', index:'Cliente', width:50, align:'right'},
                {name:'Nombre', index:'Nombre', width:150, align:'right'}, 
                {name:'ComoPaga', index:'ComoPaga', width:80, align:'right'}, 
                {name:'Articulo', index:'Articulo', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'Descripcion', index:'Descripcion', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'logo', index:'logo', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'linea', index:'linea', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'TotalArtPsos', index:'TotalArtPsos', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'PorcDesc', index:'PorcDesc', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'Cantidad', index:'Precio', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'Precio', index:'Precio', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'PComision', index:'PComision', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'Comision', index:'Comision', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'Asesor', index:'Asesor', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'Equipo', index:'Equipo', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'Refactura', index:'Refactura', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'quincena', index:'quincena', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'mes', index:'mes', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'anio', index:'anio', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'LineNum', index:'LineNum', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'SlpCode', index:'SlpCode', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'codigoLinea', index:'codigoLinea', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'U_Tipo', index:'U_Tipo', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'ModeloNegocio', index:'ModeloNegocio', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'EstatusAsesor', index:'EstatusAsesor', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'EstatusPedido', index:'EstatusPedido', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'U_Sucursal', index:'U_Sucursal', width:80, sortable:false}
            ],
            pager: '#mypager',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 500],
            viewrecords: true,
            autowidth: true,
            sortname: 'Pedido',
            sortorder: 'desc'

        });
        myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid','#mypager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true});
    });`
```

This is my php:

```
        $page = $_GET['page'];// get the requested page
        $limit = $_GET['rows'];// get how many rows we want to have into the grid
        $sidx = $_GET['sidx'];// get index row - i.e. user click to sort
        $sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction if(!$sidx)*/
        if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;
        // connect to the database
        $db = odbc_connect($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Connection Error: " . odbc_error()); 
        $result = odbc_exec($db, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM Publi_vwAdmgrPedidos"); 
        $row = odbc_fetch_array($result); 
        $count = $row['count'];
        if( $count > 0 ) {
             $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
        }
        else {
             $total_pages = 0;
        }
        if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
        $start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
        if($start <0) $start = 0; 
        $SQL = "SELECT TOP $limit * FROM Publi_vwAdmgrPedidos ORDER BY $sidx $sord";
        $result = odbc_exec($db, $SQL) or die("Couldn't execute query.".odbc_error());
        $response->page = $page;
        $response->total = $total_pages;
        $response->records = $count;
        $i=0;
        while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
         $response->rows[$i]['id']=$row['Pedido'];
         $response->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row['Sucursal'],
                                            $row['Pedido'],
                                            $row['PedidoAdpro'],
                                            $row['FechaPedido'],
                                            $row['Cancelado'],
                                            $row['FECHA_ACT'],
                                            $row['FechaEntrega'],
                                            $row['PorcDes'],
                                            $row['PC'],
                                            $row['Cliente'],
                                            $row['Nombre'],
                                            $row['ComoPaga'],
                                            $row['Articulo'],
                                            $row['Descripcion'],
                                            $row['logo'],
                                            $row['linea'],
                                            $row['TotarArtPsos'],
                                            $row['PorcDesc'],
                                            $row['Cantidad'],
                                            $row['Precio'],
                                            $row['PComision'],
                                            $row['Comision'],
                                            $row['Asesor'],
                                            $row['Equipo'],
                                            $row['Refactura'],
                                            $row['quincena'],
                                            $row['mes'],
                                            $row['anio'],
                                            $row['LineNum'],
                                            $row['SlpCode'],
                                            $row['codigoLinea'],
                                            $row['U_Tipo'],
                                            $row['ModeloNegocio'],
                                            $row['EstatusAsesor'],
                                            $row['EstatusPedido'],
                                            $row['U_Sucursal']);
         $i++;

        }
        echo json_encode($response);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `editurl` is the URL you provide that does the Create,Update,Delete functions for jqGrid's inline editing capabilities. i.e. when you edit a record on grid, the request is sent to `editurl` for processing.

You have to use the `$page` varable in you query to get the requested page and return its data as JSON. Remember, for each page, the jqGrid is asking the server to return that page but in all cases you are returning only the first page.

Your Query would probably look something like:

```
$SQL = "SELECT TOP $limit * FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()  OVER ( ORDER BY $sidx $sord)
as id_column, * FROM Publi_vwAdmgrPedidos) 
as table1 where table1.id_column >  ($page-1)*$limit ";
```

**DISCLAIMER**: I haven't checked the query, make sure it has no errors.

**EDIT:**

You can check for these parameters in your URL for search criteria. You'll have to do the search your self from DB (since you are not using local data)

```
searchField
searchString
searchOper
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't notice that, someone else helped me build the query because it was originally written for MySQL. Do you have any idea why the search function doesn't work either?

Comment: Do you want a local search or post the search request to server?

Comment: It would be best if it was an actual request to the server to get the most accurate results

Comment: I found this on the jqGrid documentation `search: the search indicator (default value _search)` I suppose I could use that value on my php when I'm doing the select as well